# Django AuthUserAdmin get_form override method being ignored

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to override the get_form method for the `AuthUserAdmin` class with something like this (taken from https://realpython.com/manage-users-in-django-admin/):

```
class AuthUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'last_login')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        is_superuser = request.user.is_superuser
        disabled_fields = set()  # type: Set[str]

        if not is_superuser:
            disabled_fields |= {
                'username',
                'is_superuser',
            }

        for f in disabled_fields:
            if f in form.base_fields:
                form.base_fields[f].disabled = True

        return form
```

However, the method is never called when the user opens the change form.

Comment: Have you unregistered the default admin class and registered yours?

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten. How can I do that?

Comment: The blog post you referred to shows you how in the section "Setup: A Custom User Admin"

Comment: Yes, now I've found it. But now all the fields are disabled or read-only.

Comment: That’s strange. You’ll need to debug more: set a breakpoint inside get_form and check the various values.

Comment: @dirkgroten, thanks for your help. Now it works as expected. The problem with all the fields set to read-only was in due to a type in `has_permission` method.